# Trying MongoDB together with Vaadin using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, vaadin7

I'm struggling with some initial setup problems!

I've a Vaadin 7 project setup within Eclipse, just some very basic application which is working properly.

But because I wanted to test with mongo I started with added the following code:

```
try {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Running this yields the following error:

```
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
```

But I'm fairly sure I added the mongodb-java-driver-2.12.0-rc0.jar to my classpath!

So, I'm puzzled why it's not working as aspected!

Regards,
Gerard

Comment: do you have your Mongo DB driver jar under WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: It's definitely missing on your classpath - how are you defining where your dependencies are?  With maven/ivy/groovy, with jar files packaged as part of the application, or are you simply pointing to a lib location somewhere?  Don't forget to check the runtime classpath, not just compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

extend your ivy.xml (if using ify) with the following dependendy:

```
<dependency org="org.mongodb" name="mongo-java-driver" rev="2.11.3"/>
```

This Version contains the necessary import for

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
```